# Hibernate hql inner join

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql, inner-join

Hi am newbie to hibernate..
I have two tables like student and phone number these two tables had a common column as student id.i want do inner join with these two table using Hibernate hql.

My Code :

```
student.java 
{
   private int id;   
   private String name;    
}

phone.java
{
    private int id;
    private int sid;//same id in student.java 
    private int phone_number;
}
```

I want hql query using inner join,student.hbm.xml and phone.hbm.xml .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ^ that is the reason I just referred him to a link!! heheh

Answer (score 2):

Read this about [Hibernate HQL Inner Join implementation](http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/associations-and-joins.shtml)